# Отправка сообщения в определённое время ASP.NET

Tags: c#, база-данных, asp.net, datetime, messenger

У меня в проекте подключена БД. В  которой есть таблица "Сообщения". В этой таблице есть поля: "ID", "Получатель", "Тема", "Дата создания", "Дата отправки сообщения", "Сообщение".

Мне нужно что бы сообщение отправлялось автоматически когда наступит дата указанная в поле "Дата отправки сообщения". (т.е. Письмо может быть создано 3 мая а отправиться должно 10 мая).

Подскажите где это реализуется (в контроллере или в сервисе) и как можно это реализовать.

Comment: пишем сервис который будет сканировать таблицу, выбирает те что требуется отправить (дата >= текущей и еще не был отправлен) и отправляет. и так периодически запускается, используя к пример CronJob

Comment: Смотрите Quartz.Net и Hangfire. | Некоторые СУБД имеют собственные возможности запуска задач по расписанию и т. п. Например, Sql Server Agent.